# Trying to move a Google drive file with googledrive package results in 403 error "A shared drive item must have exactly one parent."

Tags: r, google-drive-api, gargle

I want to move a file on a shared Google drive into a sub folder, but always getting an error.

Let's say I have folder x and sub_folder x/_old on a shared gdrive.

In folder x I have an abc.png image that I want to move to the x/_old folder.

I first retrieve the file id of that png file as well as the file/folder id of the _old folder:

```
library(googledrive)
library(tidyverse)
folder_id <- drive_ls(path = "MY_GDRIVE_PATH") |>
  filter(name == "x") |> 
  pull(id)

old_id <- drive_ls(path = folder_id, type = "folder") |>
  filter(name == "_old") |> 
  pull(id)

image_id <- drive_ls(path = folder_id) |> 
  filter(str_detect(name, "abc.png")) |> 
  pull(id)

drive_mv(file = image_id,
         path = old_id,
         overwrite = TRUE)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Error in `gargle_abort_request_failed()`:
! Client error: (403) Forbidden
A shared drive item must have exactly one parent.
• domain: global
• reason: teamDrivesParentLimit
• message: A shared drive item must have exactly one parent.
```

Any idea what's going on?

UPDATE:

A workaround by a) copying the file to the _old folder with `drive_cp` and then removing the original with `drive_trash` works, which makes me wonder if the `drive_mv` is a bit too picky here.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running `drive_auth()` and entering  '0' to obtain a new token. In the browser, I selected "View, edit and delete all your Google Drive files" option in order to give it permisson.